# Vbscript can't refresh excel workbook content

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I would like to create a script that changes a cell in every excel file in the given folder and all the files in the subfolders.

I think my code should work but the sheets can't refresh because of a security problem (I think the file has an enable content lock on it, even tho I disabled the lock in excel). I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what is going on and help me to find a solution for this?

```vb
strDate = "20190831"
strPath = "C:\lefuras_test"

Dim objFSO, objRootFolder, objFil, objXl, objWb, objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objRootFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strPath)

SearchSubFolder objRootFolder

Sub SearchSubFolder(objRootFolder)
    For Each objFil In objRootFolder.Files
        If InStr (objFil.Type, "Excel") > 0 Then
            Set Wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFil.Path)
            Wb.Sheets("CONFIG").Cells(3,2).Value=strDate
            DisableBackgroundConncections Wb
            Wb.RefreshAll
            p = objFil.Path
            Wb.SaveAs Replace(p, "C:\lefuras_test", "C:\lefuras_test_output")
            Wb.Saved = True
            wscript.echo Wb.name&" elkeszult!"
            Wb.Close True
        End If
    Next
    For Each objFolder in objRootFolder.SubFolders
        SearchSubFolder objFolder
    Next
End Sub

Sub DisableBackgroundConncections(Wb)
    For Each connection in Wb.Connections
        If connection.Type = xlConnectionTypeOLEDB Then
            connection.OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

objExcel.Quit
wscript.echo "Folyamat vege."
```

Comment: For starters, `xlConnectionTypeOLEDB` has no meaning in VB Script. Replace it with its literal value `1`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the value but the problem still persists.

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out I was wrong because I was checking for OLEDB connection instead of ODBC but refreshAll() still didn't work so I did a workaroung by refreshing all individually.

```vb
strDate = "20190830"
strPath = "C:\lefuras_test"
strOutputPath = "C:\lefuras_test_output"

Dim objFSO, objRootFolder, objFil, objXl, objWb, objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
Set objRootFolder = objFSO.getfolder(strPath)

objExcel.AutomationSecurity = 3
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.AskToUpdateLinks = False
objExcel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = False

SearchSubFolder objRootFolder

Sub SearchSubFolder(objRootFolder)
    For Each objFil In objRootFolder.Files
        If InStr (objFil.Type, "Excel") > 0 Then
            Set Wb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(objFil.Path)
            Wb.Sheets("CONFIG").Cells(3,2).Value=strDate
            DisableBackgroundConncections Wb
            p = objFil.Path
            Wb.SaveAs Replace(p, strPath, strOutputPath)
            Wb.Saved = True
            wscript.echo Wb.name&" elkeszult!"
            Wb.Close True
        End If
    Next
    For Each objFolder in objRootFolder.SubFolders
        SearchSubFolder objFolder
    Next
End Sub

Sub DisableBackgroundConncections(Wb)
    For Each connection in Wb.Connections
        If connection.Type = 2 Then
            connection.ODBCConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
            connection.ODBCConnection.backgroundquery = false
            connection.ODBCConnection.EnableRefresh = true
            connection.Refresh
        End If
    Next
End Sub

objExcel.Quit
wscript.echo "Folyamat vege."
```